# Any way to maintain a partial index on only the highest element in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I need to

```
SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM someTable
```

whenever my application starts up. The table is enormous (billions of rows). The index on `created_at` that I created to make this query fast is using up multiple gigabytes. Is there a way to create some kind of partial index only on the highest element? Or any way to make this take up less space? Or an alternate approach entirely? All I ever need to query on this column is the maximum element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best is to take an alternative approach and *not* to query the large table all the time, if that is the only purpose of the index.

Create a second table that only contains a single timestamp and define a trigger on `sometable` that updates that small table whenever a new row arrives or an old one is updated.

This approach will only work well if you never delete the row with the latest `created_at` or never update `created_at` to an earlier timestamp.

Comment: Good idea! Thank you. I will create a second table that is updated using a trigger. In fact, it's strictly increasing and rows are never updated nor deleted, so I can just do something on insert to the main table like UPDATE cachedtablename SET max_created_at = ? WHERE max_created_at < ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford to have this information not always up-to-date, you can can create a materialized view:

```
create materialized view my_view as select max(created_at) from my_table;
```

And you only need to run (which should be very fast):

```
select max from my_view;
```

This object takes very little space. However everytime that you need to have this materialized view updated, you need to refresh it and without an index it will need to scan the whole table:

```
refresh materialized view my_view;
```